# How actually card table and writer barrier work?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am reading some materials about garbage collection in Java in order to get to know more deeply what really happens in GC process.

I came across on the mechanism called "card table". I've Googled for it and haven't found comprehensive information. Most of explanations are rather shallow and describes it like some magic.

My question is: How card table and write barrier works? What is marked in card tables? How then garbage collector knows that particular object is referenced by another object persisted in older generation.

I would like to have some practical imagination about that mechanism, like I was supposed to prepare some simulation.

Comment: To get into such a deep theory, you can try this book http://gchandbook.org/contents.html. It provides quiet comprehensive overview.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I don't know whether you found some exceptionally bad description or whether you expect too many details, I've been quite satisfied with the [explanations I've seen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2009/03/02/back-to-basics-generational-garbage-collection.aspx). If the descriptions are brief and sound simplistic, that's because it really is a rather simple mechanism.

As you apparently already know, a generational garbage collector needs to be able to enumerate old objects that refer to young objects. It would be correct to scan all old objects, but that destroys the advantages of the generational approach, so you have to narrow it down. Regardless of how you do that, you need a write barrier - a piece of code executed whenever a member variable (of a reference type) is assigned/written to. If the new reference points to a young object and it's stored in an old object, the write barrier records that fact for the garbage collect. The difference lies in how it's recorded. There are exact schemes using so-called remembered sets, a collection of *every* old object that has (had at some point) a reference to a young object. As you can imagine, this takes quite a bit of space.

The card table is a trade-off: Instead of telling you which objects *exactly* contains young pointers (or at least did at some point), it groups objects into fixed-sized buckets and tracks which buckets contain objects with young pointers. This, of course, reduces space usage. For correctness, it doesn't really matter how you bucket the objects, as long as you're consistent about it. For efficiency, you just group them by their memory address (because you have that available for free), divided by some larger power of two (to make the division a cheap bitwise operation).

Also, instead of maintaining an explicit list of buckets, you reserve some space for each possible bucket up-front. Specifically, there is an array of N bits or bytes, where N is the number of buckets, so that the `i`th value is 0 if the `i`th bucket contains no young pointers, or 1 if it does contain young pointers. This is the card table proper. Typically this space is allocated and freed along with a large block of memory used as (part of) the heap. It may even be embedded in the start of the memory block, if it doesn't need to grow. Unless the entire address space is used as heap (which is very rare), the above formula gives numbers starting from `start_of_memory_region >> K` instead of 0, so to get an index into the card table you have to subtract the start of the start address of the heap.

In summary, when the write barrier finds that the statement `some_obj.field = other_obj;` stores a young pointer in an old object, it does this:

```
card_table[(&old_obj - start_of_heap) >> K] = 1;
```

Where `&old_obj` is the address of the object that now has a young pointer (which is already in a register because it was just determined to refer to an old object).
During minor GC, the garbage collector looks at the card table to determine which heap regions to scan for young pointers:

```
for i from 0 to (heap_size >> K):
    if card_table[i]:
        scan heap[i << K .. (i + 1) << K] for young pointers
```

Comment: If the card table indicates that some references held in some chunk of gen1 storage have been updated, how would the system identify which parts of that chunk held references?  Does the system need to keep and traverse a linked list of all gen1 objects to find the starting addresses of any objects that are at least partially within the touched block?

Comment: Serious question: Now after the GC runs, the card table is reset. What happens if the old object did not update a reference to the young object, and then the next GC cycle kicks in??? will the young object be wiped, despite that the old object might still be referencing or needing it???

Comment: @AhmadTn: why would the card table be reset when the GC runs? For a young collection I'd expect the card table to be kept intact.

Comment: am i correct about this situation? if there is no pointer to young object in the old object (previously it has but now it doesnt anymore). The card table entry for it be reseted in next young collection because the GC couldnt find any

Answer (score 20):

Sometime ago I have written an article explaining mechanics of young collection in HotSpot JVM.
[Understanding GC pauses in JVM, HotSpot's minor GC](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/06/understanding-gc-pauses-in-jvm-hotspots.html)

> Principle of dirty card write-barrier is very simple. Each time when program modifies reference in memory, it should mark modified memory page as dirty. There is a special card table in JVM and each 512 byte page of memory has associated one byte entry in card table.
>
> Normally collection of all references from old space to young would require scanning through all objects in old space. That is why we need write-barrier. All objects in young space have been created (or relocated) since last reset of write-barrier, so non-dirty pages cannot have references into young space. This means we can scan only object in dirty pages.

Answer (score 15):

For anyone who is looking for a simple answer:

In JVM, the memory space of objects is broken down into two spaces:

- Young generation (space): All new allocations (objects) are created inside this space.
- Old generation (space): This is where long lived objects exist (and probably die)

The idea is that, once an object survives a few garbage collection, it is more likely to survive for a long time. So, objects that survive garbage collection for more than a threshold, will be promoted to old generation. The garbage collector runs more frequently in the young generation and less frequently in the old generation. This is because most objects live for a very short time.

We use generational garbage collection to avoid scanning of the whole memory space (like Mark and Sweep approach). In JVM, we have a **minor garbage collection** which is when GC runs inside the young generation and a **major garbage collection (or full GC)** which encompasses garbage collection of both young and old generations.

When doing minor garbage collection, JVM follows every reference from the live roots to the objects in the young generation, and marks those objects as live, which excludes them from the garbage collection process. The problem is that there may be some references from the objects in the old generation to the objects in young generation, which should be considered by GC, meaning those objects in young generation that are referenced by objects in old generation should also be marked as live and excluded from the garbage collection process.

One approach to solve this problem is to scan all of the objects in the old generation and find their references to young objects. But this approach is in contradiction with the idea of generational garbage collectors. (Why we broke down our memory space into multiple generations in the first place?)

Another approach is using write barriers and card table. When an object in old generation writes/updates a reference to an object in the young generation, this action goes through something called write barrier. When JVM sees these write barriers, it updates the corresponding entry in the card table. Card table is a table, which each one of its entries correspond to 512 bytes of the memory. You can think of it as an array containing `0` and `1` items. A `1` entry means there is an object in the corresponding area of the memory which contains references to objects in young generation.

Now, when minor garbage collection is happening, first every reference from the live roots to young objects are followed and the referenced objects in young generation will be marked as live. Then, instead of scanning all of the old object to find references to the young objects, the card table is scanned. If GC finds any marked area in the card table, it loads the corresponding object and follows its references to young objects and marks them as live either.

Comment: Serious question: Now after the GC runs, the card table is reset. What happens if the old object did not update a reference to the young object, and then the next GC cycle kicks in??? will the young object be wiped, despite that the old object might still be referencing or needing it???

Comment: @AhmadTn why would the card table be reseted? it is alive and well for as long as the application is.