# Does using ?? (null-coalescing operator) to conditionally update a value execute unecessary read and write?

Tags: c#, performance, null-coalescing-operator

Is the use of `??` to update a value only when a new value exists equivalent to the use of a conditional, or is it less efficient?

I.e. in `bar.Foo = qux.Foo ?? bar.Foo`, when `qux.Foo == null` and the value defaults to `bar.Foo`, is that interpreted as a "do nothing", or as "read `bar.Foo` -> write to `bar.Foo`"?

*Long version:*

I have a PATCH endpoint. When the front end sends the JSON data, each property is updated if, and only if, it is not null. Let's call the current object `bar`, the received DTO `qux` and the relevant property `Foo`.

I believe this is the "regular" way of doing it:

```
if (qux.Foo != null)
{
    bar.Foo = qux.Foo;
}
```

However, I have a personal preference for the use of ?? here.

```
bar.Foo = qux.Foo ?? bar.Foo
```

<sub>It just looks prettier.</sub>

Now, something that occurred to me is that my code might be performing an unnecessary read and an unnecessary write, which could be pretty bad given that we work with base64 conversion so some props can get as large as several MBs.

The truth is I have no idea how to go about measuring this by myself, and couldn't find an answer anywhere.

Comment: In response to your comment about the several MBs, since you're dealing with reference types it doesn't matter how big the objects are. You're only assigning references (a single 32-/64-bit value).

Comment: [You can see for yourself](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4hW7ob75z). The call to `CORINFO_HELP_ASSIGN_REF` will trigger a write. It's just a reference, so the write is fast. However, it dirties the card, so it adds more work for the GC.

Comment: @RaymondChen It's a property, not a field, so who knows what the setter is doing.  It could have a 10 second sleep in it for all we know.  Or it could be empty and be removed as a no-op because it doesn't actually store the set value anywhere.

Comment: @Servy I assumed the question was about the cost of a write, whether the write is directly to a field or indirectly through a property. (I'm rejecting the pathological property setter that doesn't actually set anything.) A reference write has to go through the write barrier, which dirties the card. It also dirties the page (so the OS has more work) and dirties the cache line (so the CPU has more work). And if you look at the code gen, it still takes a jump, so you aren't avoiding a branch mispredict either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will perform a write. The reason (other than the fact that you explicitly coded it that way) is because your property might have a setter that would not be called if the seemingly pointless write were optimized away.

As mentioned in the comments, there should be no performance concern because you are just copying a *reference* to an object, not the object itself. It might be different if you were using a `struct` that copies by value, but even in that case the "regular" way of doing it would be perfectly fine.

In fact I would not even fault you for inlining the `if` in this case:

```
if (qux.Foo != null) bar.Foo = qux.Foo;
```

Comment: There is a GC performance penalty because the write will dirty the card and add it to the memory that has to be scanned at the next GC. [Card marking discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154607/how-actually-card-table-and-writer-barrier-work) (for java, but C# works basically the same way). Even without the card penalty, it dirties the page and forces a write to disk at the next page-out. Also dirties the cache line and could impact multiprocessor performance.

Comment: Would not a trivial setter be inlined, and then subject to further optimization, possibly including elimination of the write?

Comment: It's _possible_, but then the optimizer have to make sure that the `Foo` _getter_ does nothing significant to remove it as well. Best to just remove all doubt and either explicitly call the setter or explicitly _not_ call the setter.